# Best way to set up my AE project?

Tags: after-effects, video-editor

In a nutshell, I just got a new job where I have to create at least 30 MP4 files a day cutting different parts of music videos (even from the same one).
They will provide me the videos to download and I have to make different MP4s in After Effects **not longer than 8 secs**.

---

I was thinking of doing it this way:

Project in AE **(10 sec composition)** with 3 project folder

- Footage: full-length videos
- Cut Footage: cut videos pre-composed

> Here is a problem: cutting in AE is so annoying and (because the main comp is 10 seconds) I have to **extend the new composition from 10 sec to the length of the video**, find the relevant part, put two markers and **reduce again the composition** within the markers. Finally, I have to move the pre-comp in the main composition where I can start with the effects and stuff. I do all of this because I want more control of the layers, for this reason I prefer to keep a fixed length layer rather than a reduced layer, like in the screen below:
>
> [image: screen]

- Render: the folder where I put the pre-comps formed by *cut footage pre-comp + effects*

> What is the better way of making a rendering queue in AE?

---

So the worst part is cutting, but what about the size of the project? I mean, should I create an *After Effects Project* every day that includes 30 MP4 files with of course all of the effects, layers, videos, etc. or is it going to be to excessive? Do I have other options?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using After Effects for this? Seems a bit overkill and there are MUCH easier ways of doing this. Premiere Pro seems like it would be a more natural choice for cutting down video into little segments like that.

Comment: Agree with John, but if you're allergic to using Premiere or really need AE for some reason, there's a tool here that will automatically adjust the length of the comp to the first or last frames of the layers in it, even if they extend past the end: http://blob.pureandapplied.com.au/first-n-last/ full disclosure: I wrote it.

Comment: That's amazing @stib! Anyway I'm totally fine with Premier Pro, but I don't know, I should create a dynamic link everytime? Or maybe there is a future that I don't know like: cut the video and just drag and drop in After Effects?

Comment: Why are you moving it to After Effects at all? If you're on Windows, you can export a GIF straight from Premiere Pro. If not, you can export the video (segment) from Premiere and use one of a myriad of tools to convert the video to a GIF (like giphy.com)

Comment: Right, I wasn't clear about the format, I'm sorry!
We use the term "GIF" because is what looks like, but on the CMS I send a normal MP4.
Anyway I need AE because I make proper small lyric videos with lights, effects and everything, Premiere is not able to do anything like that.So I must cut and work on AE, finally make the render.

Comment: Okay, I think you're definitely missing some key info in your question then. I'm guessing your "footage" is then the raw footage (no effects), and you must add effects/lights/etc. Why is your "main comp" 10 seconds? Can you not just create a new composition each time?

Comment: Yeah man, huge mistake in my explanation, sorry!
It's getting easier than what it seemed before, isn't it? Ahah! 
Well, your comment just made me realise that if I drag and drop the footage on the Composition Icon (even if the audio preview of AE is sh*t) it will fit perfectly, than I can use that script for cutting and finally, work on the video without using ANOTHER pre-comp containing the footage.

Update: the script is no more available. 
But I found a cheap one: http://aescripts.com/trim-to-comp-contents/

Comment: I found that this was a very useful tutorial on ways of setting up multiple renders - you might find it helps (not with the trimming your comp part, just the rest): https://vimeo.com/12875270

Comment: That's great @tomh!
Anyway I found a solution about cutting.
I can upload the video on Premiere Pro, cut and select "Replace With After Effects Composition" and that's it, that future is amazing for this type of work! Thank you all by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution about cutting. I can upload the video on Premiere Pro, cut and select "Replace With After Effects Composition" and that's it, that feature is amazing for this type of work! Thank you all by the way!